# ArrayList of Arraylits

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to use 10 ArrayLists for a project, instead of creating 10 separate arraylists. I was told to use: `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();` and to create the 10 arrays to use: `for(int i=0;i<10;i++){ lists.add(new ArrayList<Integer> ());`

I have never studied arraylists inside of a arraylist, so this is very new to me. How do I access the arrays inside of the array? They do not have a name that I can see to access, so how do I call each individual arraylist?

Comment: How would you get any element within a list?

Comment: I just need to know how to access each individual created arraylist for the project, I don't even know how to call one of the inner arraylists. I know how to use the arraylists and the methods, I just don't understand how to access them within the larger arraylist

Comment: Simply think you have a list of objects. Each of those objects happens to be another list. If you know how to use one list, then using the inner one should be easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a number to a list in the list of lists, you have to `get` it using its index, then you can `add` to it.

```
lists.get(0).add(42);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create an arraylist of arraylists as shown in the code below. If you want to access all the inner array lists just use a for each loop. If you want a specific list (array list is ordered) just use the index (both ways are shown in the example below):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> firstList = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("A");
    add("B");
    add("C");
}};

ArrayList<String> secondList = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("D");
    add("E");
    add("F");
}};


listOfLists.add(firstList);
listOfLists.add(secondList);

//access all inner lists
for(ArrayList<String> innerList:listOfLists) {
    System.out.println("INNER LIST --> "+innerList);
}

//access specific list
System.out.println(listOfLists.get(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Let say you wanna access some index of a particular ArrayList inside the ArrayList of ArrayList

e.g.

```
arrayListOfarrayList.get(indexOfArrayList).get(indexOfElement);
```

If you wanna add something

```
arrayListOfarrayList.get(indexOfArrayList).add(yourElement);
```

You can refer to ArrayList API docs for more details
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: It should be `arrayListOfarrayList.get(indexOfArrayList).add(element);`